# Derivatives of an expansion of a function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, orthonormal, spherical-harmonics

Recall that, for fixed $j \in Z_+\cup \{0\}$, a spherical harmonic of degree $j$ is the restriction to $S^{n-1}$ of a harmonic polynomial on $R^n$ that is homogeneous of degree $j$. Let $Y_{j,1}\, ,Y_{j,2}\,\ldots, Y_{j,d_{n-1}(j)}$ be an orthonormal basis of the subspace in $L^{2}(S^{n-1})$ of degree $j$ spherical harmonics; here, $\displaystyle{d_{n-1}(j):={n+j-1\choose j}}$.

Consider for $j$ even the following expansion:
$$
F=Y_{0,1}+\sum_{j,k}(-1)^{j/2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+j}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac j2\right)}f_{j,k} Y_{j,k},
$$

How to find all $n$-th derivatives of $F$?

Comment: I’m not so familiar with this topic. You mean with respect to n?

Comment: No, I would like to find $n$-th derivative. The problem is that the spherical harmonics is a multi variable function and I do not know how to differentiate it...